# Mouse + Trackball combo

Tags: mice, trackball

I tried a Logitech trackball when they first came out as I was starting to get RSI on the wrist.  But it soon gave me RSI of the thumb.  So I went back to the mouse and made myself ambidextrous.  I split the usage to both hands.

When I google for a mouse+trackball, they look like a mouse with trackball.  But I can not be sure if they work as a mouse too.

Looking for Mouse / Trackball combo, not much larger than a normal mouse size.